# Strings in classes using std:string name

Tags: c++, string, header

I was running into an error telling me string was not a type. So I looked up on here and found out that std::string name; to be in the header, but when I compile the program it tells me that name was not declared in the scope.

here is my code for the header:

```
#ifndef INMATE_H
#define INMATE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Inmate
{
public:
    Inmate();
    int getID();
    std::string getName();
    //int getHeightFt();
    //int getHeightInch();
    void setID(int x);
    //void setName():
    //void setHeightFt();
    //void setHeightInch();

private:
    int idNumber;
    std::string name;
    //int heightFt;
    //int heightInch;

};

#endif // INMATE_H
```

and this is my cpp file code

```
#include "Inmate.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

Inmate::Inmate()
{
    cout << "What is the inmates name"<<endl;
    cin >> name;
}

void Inmate :: setID(int x){
    idNumber = x;
}

int Inmate :: getID(){
    return idNumber;
}
string getName(){
    return name;
}
```

Comment: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: This problem has absolutely nothing to do with strings...

Comment: I haven't done any coding in a long while.  It's been even longer since the last time I used this site. I have pretty much forgotten all code, and while I have recently been considering jumping back in, code is not the reason I came back. I logged in to check a post about possible worth in fixing or recycling old mini fridges, and I seen this very old post. It pretty great that stack keeps these. Now I have a decent repository, for lack of a better word, on my old code and old mistakes to relearn from.  @Boundry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `Inmate` prefix on your `getName()` method.

```
string Inmate::getName(){
    return name;
}
```

Without that prefix, the function `getName` exists in the global scope, and `name` is resolved in the global scope instead of the class scope. Since there is no `name` variable in the global scope, the compiler reports an error.

Comment: Thanks! Guess I am so use to java. cpp files have been giving me fits.

Comment: @JayB901662, Very understandable. I also came from a Java background.